# Would 650w PSU be enough for GTX 970 & GTX 960 sli?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, computer-building, nvidia-graphics-card, sli

Title says it all.

My specs(Currently):

- i7 Quad Core 4790 3.6GHz
- Asus Z97-E Mobo (Supports SLI)
- 16GB HyperX Fury RAM (2x 8GB)
- NVIDIA Geforce GTX 970 4GB
- 1TB Hard drive
- Corsair H55 Water Cooler
- Corsair 650w PSU: 80+ Gold Certified

I would like to add in a GTX 960 to make this an SLI with the 970 I have.
Will all of this work if I done this and would I need to upgrade the PSU as I don't want to upgrade PSU if not neccessary?

Comment: You can't SLI a 960 with a 970, they have to match for SLI. 650W is potentially plausible but usually considered not enough (750W for headroom). Please provide exact PSU model -- not all "650W" PSUs are made equal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Graphics card and PSU requirement](http://superuser.com/questions/1035218/graphics-card-and-psu-requirement)

Answer (score 3):

As Ash said, you can't SLI 2 different models of video card.  They can be different manufacturer's and have different clock speeds but they have to be the same model and memory size. http://www.geforce.com/whats-new/guides/introduction-to-sli-technology-guide#4

Newegg and this Outervision site have psu calculators. http://images10.newegg.com/BizIntell/tool/psucalc/index.html?name=Power-Supply-Wattage-Calculator

http://outervision.com/power-supply-calculator

**ANSWER**: If you dont' have an optical drive and were to use 2 970's, Newegg recommends an 808W PSU.

***These posts mention being able to SLI non-matching GPU models in Win 10, with DX12 but it sounds like it will require the game to also be running DX12 and the game decides how to divide processing http://www.overclock.net/t/1568936/is-it-possible-to-sli-a-960-and-a-970-together

http://www.tomshardware.com/news/microsoft-directx12-amd-nvidia,28606.html